# R: Plot the famous "6 degrees of separation" (Kevin Bacon)

Tags: r, graph, nodes, edges, subgraph

I am trying to write some R code that shows degrees of separation between friends. That is, suppose I pick the "node" with the arrow pointing towards it, and I say "degree = 3", I would like to be able to identify the following path in this network:[image]

I think I found a previous post on stackoverflow that answers a similar question: [R Igraph subgraph given node index and number of nodes to include in the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390780/r-igraph-subgraph-given-node-index-and-number-of-nodes-to-include-in-the-graph)

Suppose I create some fake network data :

```
library(igraph)
file <-data.frame(
    
    "source" = c(
        "John",
        "John",
        "Tim",
        "Tim",
        "Alex",
        "Andrew",
        "Andrew",
        "Andrew",
        "Oliver",
        "Oliver",
        "Oliver",
        "Matt",
        "Steven",
        "Steven",
        "Steven",
        "Matt",
        "Charles",
        "Charles",
        "Charles",
        "Sean",
        "Ted",
        "Ryan",
        "Ryan",
        "Ryan",
        "Ted",
        "Phil",
        "Phil",
        "Phil",
        "Sam",
        "Toby",
        "Toby",
        "Donald",
        "Donald",
        "Donald",
        "Mitch",
        "Mitch",
        "Mitch"),
    
    "target" = c("Sam",
                 "Tim",
                 "Alex",
                 "Matt",
                 "Andrew",
                 "Sean",
                 "Peter",
                 "Ben",
                 "Kevin",
                 "Thomas",
                 "Dave",
                 "Steven",
                 "Kenny",
                 "Derek",
                 "CJ",
                 "Charles",
                 "Ivan",
                 "Kyle",
                 "Andrew",
                 "Ted",
                 "Ryan",
                 "Daniel",
                 "Chris",
                 "Scott",
                 "Phil",
                 "Henry",
                 "George",
                 "Paul",
                 "Toby",
                 "Donald",
                 "Mitch",
                 "Jack",
                 "Luke",
                 "Myles",
                 "Elliot",
                 "Harvey",
                 "Owen")
    
)

graph <- graph.data.frame(file, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)
plot(graph)
```

Is this the correct code for plotting 3 degrees of separation for "John"?

```
distan <- 3

subnetwork <- induced.subgraph(graph, vids = as.vector(unlist(neighborhood(graph, distan, nodes = "John", mode = 'all'))))

plot(subnetwork)
```

Is there a way to find out "who has the most friends" in this network? (the node with the most connections)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works  but I believe that use of `neighborhood` is deprecated. Instead, it might be better to use.

```
distan <- 3
subnetwork <- induced.subgraph(graph, unlist(ego(graph, order=3, nodes="John")))
```

To find out who has the most friends, use the degree function.

```
degree(graph)
   John     Tim    Alex  Andrew  Oliver    Matt  Steven Charles    Sean     Ted 
      2       3       2       5       3       3       4       4       2       3 
   Ryan    Phil     Sam    Toby  Donald   Mitch   Peter     Ben   Kevin  Thomas 
      4       4       2       3       4       4       1       1       1       1 
   Dave   Kenny   Derek      CJ    Ivan    Kyle  Daniel   Chris   Scott   Henry 
      1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1 
 George    Paul    Jack    Luke   Myles  Elliot  Harvey    Owen 
      1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Andrew has the most friends.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961299/r-significance-testing?noredirect=1#comment114847438_64961299  does this mean the first community is significant? Thank you

Comment: Thank you... last question : suppose there are 3 communities. Is there a way of finding out which community is the most "important"?

Comment: You would have to define importance - and I don't think hat there is a single definition of that. It might be the biggest community,  but there can be graphs where a small community connects together two larger communities. The small one is important for maintaining communications.

Comment: D = Degree(graph)  ... is there a way to organize this better? Deg = table(Degree(graph))?  ... is there a way to sort "D"?

Comment: Sure.  simply `sort(D)`

Comment: I will add a cooment at the other question.

Comment: Thank you again...do you have any idea about the other question left in the discussion there? "is there a way of finding out which communities are connected to each each other? (i.e. once a community has been "contracted", can you see which other communities are connected to it?)" ... much Appreciated