# R: Significance Testing

Tags: r, function, graph, nodes

I am trying to use a function I found that serves to test the significance of an object created an igraph.

First the data and the libraries are loaded. Then, clustering is performed on the data. Finally, I use a function I found online in an attempt to calculate the significance of the clustering. However, this does not work.

Can someone please help me understand why this function for significance testing is not working?

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
data(karate)

cfg <- cluster_fast_greedy(karate)
plot(cfg, karate) 


a = induced_subgraph(karate, cfg[[1]])
    



#community significance test (http://igraph.wikidot.com/community-detection-in-r)

 community.significance.test <- function(graph, vs, ...) {
    if (is.directed(graph)) stop("This method requires an undirected graph")
    subgraph <- induced.subgraph(graph, vs)
    in.degrees <- degree(subgraph)
    out.degrees <- degree(graph, vs) - in.degrees
    wilcox.test(in.degrees, out.degrees, ...)
}

#test the significance of the first community

aa = community.significance.test(karate,a)

 Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, vids) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Thanks

Comment: The `vs` parameter should be a vertex sequence, not a graph itself. The proper way to call the function is `community.significance.test(karate,cfg[[1]])` (but with this example you run into problems due to ties`). You can turn off exact pvalues with `community.significance.test(karate,cfg[[1]], exact=FALSE)`

Comment: thank you! the output: Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  in.degrees and out.degrees
W = 312, p-value = 1.271e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
this means the null hypothesis is rejected and the community is significant?

Comment: this is the code I ran: community.significance.test(karate,cfg[[1]], exact=FALSE)

Comment: @MrFlick : do you have any thoughts about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960236/formatting-graphs-in-r   do cluster communities have inherent linkages between them? or are these linkages arbitrary?

Comment: OP asked me if the first cluster is significant. Yes. You got  `p-value = 1.271e-0`  Typically people accept any p less than 0.05 as significant.